# Ex9.pag.48 Linear algebra done right

Tags: linear-algebra

If $v_1,...,v_m$ is linearly independent, then $span(v_1+w,...,v_m+w)$ has dimension $≥m−1$

I solved it using linearly independent list: $v_2-v_1,v_3-v_1,...,v_m-v_1$

My question: why I cannot just say that linearly independent list:
$v_1, v_2, ...,v_{m-1}$ is included in $span(v_1+w,...,v_m+w)$ and it is linearly independent, so
$\dim span(v_1+w,...,v_m+w) ≥\dim span (v_1, ...,v_{m-1}) = m-1$

Comment: If you use dollar signs around your mathematical expressions, they will be formatted prettier. This is called latex. Could you try it?

Comment: Yeah, I tried, but nothing happens or I cannot see how it looks until I don't publish my question?

Comment: @Ild What exactly do you mean when you say that the list $v_1, v_2, ...,v_{m-1}$ "is included in" $\text{span}(v_1+w,...,v_m+w)$? How do you know that this is the case?

Comment: Umm, because it's not true?  Try for example $v_1 = (1, 0, 0), v_2 = (0, 1, 0), w = (0, 0, 1)$ where $\operatorname{span}(v_1+w, v_2+w) = \{(x,y,z) \mid z=x+y\}$ does not have either $v_1$ or $v_2$ as elements.

Comment: Why are you looking at differences of the vectors $v_i$?

Comment: @TedShifrin those differences are linearly independent, and included in $\text{span}(v_1+w,...,v_m+w)$, therefore they show the span has dimension at least $m-1$.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, here is your proposed proof, translated to the case $m = 2$.

Then supposing $v_1$, $v_2$ are linearly independent, and $w$ is any vector, then $v_1$ is included in the span of $\{ v_1 - w, v_2 - w \}$.

But this is not true. Set $w = v_1$, then $\{v_1 - w, v_2 \} = \{ 0, v_2\}$. So the span does not contain $v_1$.